Is it possible to change from a LVM + Raid 1 setup to LVM on a live system?
This might be a silly question. But here goes -
Some time ago I setup a Ubuntu Server system which contained two identical drives. Both drives were setup during the installation process using LVM + Raid 1.
I would guess what this really means is that I created a Raid device first and then used LVM on top of that. But I could be mistaken. There might be a way to figure it out.
This system runs a data store. (Kafka to be exact. If you're not familiar with Kafka just pretend it's hosting a database.)
The problem it I'm about to run out of disk. There's about 5 % remaining.
I tried some stuff to archive data to another system, but I realized this probably isn't going to work so I've sort of run out of options.
As a last resort, I am wondering if there is a way to break the Raid and combine both disks together using LVM.
I realize what I am asking for here is really quite challenging. Particularly as the root partition is part of this setup.
To give some idea about the current configuration, here is the output of sudo blkid.
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="2A2B-A491" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="a1d02797-..."
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="3f3f1c59-..." UUID_SUB="ff3db717-..." LABEL="ubuntu-server:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="b4de5c71-..."
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="4bd2d087-..." UUID_SUB="4ca62bb9-..." LABEL="ubuntu-server:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="51457661-..."
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="db2acc5a-..." UUID_SUB="36fa3f0e-..." LABEL="ubuntu-server:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="e96c4c38-..."
/dev/nvme1n1p1: UUID="2971-0B61" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="3fbcd197-..."
/dev/nvme1n1p2: UUID="3f3f1c59-..." UUID_SUB="6667f123-..." LABEL="ubuntu-server:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="81aed881-..."
/dev/nvme1n1p3: UUID="4bd2d087-..." UUID_SUB="453744c7-..." LABEL="ubuntu-server:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="f1b24cab-..."
/dev/nvme1n1p4: UUID="db2acc5a-..." UUID_SUB="8c55099f-..." LABEL="ubuntu-server:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="ffd89d37-..."
/dev/md0p1: UUID="9358becb-..." BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="cc0d0a6a-..."
/dev/md1p1: UUID="4ca79c3f-..." TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="4015b3d7-..."
/dev/md2p1: UUID="e53db31b-..." BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="f845a5c8-..."
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"

Edit: Add my fstab as well.
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/md2p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-db2acc5a:5b5d5857:4aee9cd1:ed870c54-part1 / ext4 defaults 0 1
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-4bd2d087:730cb833:6b45fb58:02da4edf-part1 none swap sw 0 0
# /boot was on /dev/md0p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-3f3f1c59:03b93352:9d75141a:42c0469e-part1 /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme1n1p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2971-0B61 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1


I mean even theoretically, this must not be a problem: The whole point of RAID 1 is that if one disk fails, the other disk can function alone.
So, worst case: you just remove one physical store, the RAID 1 is "degraded" (i.e., there's no mirroring, but then you go ahead, and just copy its content to a new LVM volume on the space formerly used by the mirror. Then you remove the original RAID1, and use the freed space to extend your LVM volume.

I'm not sure what exactly you mean with RAID1+lvm. If that happens to be lvmraid (see man lvmraid): The more elegant way (and what I'd recommend to avoid a full-disk copy) is to convert the lvmraid 1 to linear:
lvconvert -m0 my_volume_group/my_volume

-m is for "number of mirrors". Setting it to 0 means removing the mirroring altogether.
Afterwards, you'll want to lvresize -l 100%FREE -r my_volume_group/my_volume to use the freed space for your volume.

Serious question though: A while ago you thought your Kafka instance was so important that you wanted to have full failover in case of a storage device fail, now you can't even afford larger SSDs. That doesn't sound like a consistent development strategy.
Are you sure this is the way to go? Will you regret this decision soon?
I'd argue that RAID1 is almost never a good idea to begin with: you get the "slowest writer defines highest possible speed at any given moment" problem, and your system won't even notice if the two copies disagree due to, say, one experiencing a bitflip; and even if the system somehow noticed the discrepancy (it doesn't), there would be no way of knowing which copy is right. So, IMHO, RAID1 with two disks only makes sense atop of integrity-checked volumes! So, the layering would be physical storage under a dm-integrity layer under an LVM RAID. (Much easier would be to use ZFS with zraid and data checksums, that would actually do the check whether all data read is correct.) And even then, with two identical SSDs with identical data load, chances are that if one fails, the other is already likely to be close to failing, so, you need to be darn fast at replacing that failed SSD.
Kafka itself brings replication; that might be the solution here: instead of mirroring the storage within one machine, you have two machines, and set the replication factor of all topics to 2.

I agree with your comments about RAID1 making not much sense. When I originally set this up, it was to protect against total disk failures, in the event that one of the disks failed, as you mention, it could just be removed and the system would continue to function until the data was migrated.

Originally I intended to use Kafka for persistant storage. To be honest, it isn't ideal for this. The fact that consumer groups will automatically garbage collect themselves after a week isn't ideal. It means if a consumer goes offline and for some reason it is not noticed for a week (I've had this happen) then it need some manual work to reset the offset. Not ideal. You can of course extend the 1 week period, but there is no way to make it indefinite afaik.

It's probably better to use Kafka for data ingestion and nothing else, or for data in motion. Not long term storage. I tried to archive the data to a database, but I found the database was too slow. I get about 100 events/second, and there are over 100M events to archive, so this isn't really feasible. I might be able to speed up the process by making the database connector asynchronous, but to be honest this is a much bigger task and may come with its own problems.

A specific question though: What might I do to determine if I am using lvmraid? Could I get this information from parted, perhaps? It's a Ubuntu Server 22.04 system. I would have done the most straightforward thing during the setup. From what I remember it was painful to get Debian setup on top of a RAID1 device, whereas for Ubuntu Server it was much better supported. The boot partition, swap and root partitions are all on RAID1 devices, as far as I can tell.

does lvs -o name,segtype (this is from man lvmraid, as recommended) show any lvm volumes with a raid type?

No, the output from that command is blank. It prints nothing at all, just returns to the command prompt. Is that what you would expect? I don't recall ever seeing this command before so that might suggest it is unlikely to be setup in this way.

that shouldn't be blank if you're really, as the title of your question says, use LVM? Did you run as root / with sudo?

Yeah I did - in that case, it may be possible that none of these devices are using LVM at all. It might be that there are identical partitions on both drives, and then 3 MD devices on top of that. Is lvs the CLI for LVM, or is there another LVM command which could be used to check for LVM devices?

btw, unsure if this is helpful, but I'm playing with lvm. sudo lvm. lvm> fullreport (output is blank) - does that suggest LVM is not in use at all?

I realized I should have added my fstab details as well. I have added those too.

@user3728501 I'm not sure what sudo lvm should be doing without a command; sudo lvs should display the LVM logical volumes, that's why I made you run it with the added info of outputting whether segments where linear or raidN.

Ok, perhaps I need to edit my question or ask a new one, as it looks like this LVM thing was a red-herring and probably does not exist.
